# Increase WordPress memory limit - Current memory limit: 40 MB | We recommend setting memory to at least 128MB -

Tags: php, wordpress, apache2

I currently have this notice in my wordpress dashboard.

[image]

I have set the php limit to 128m in my loaded config file. I then echo'd out info and it says 128m

[image]

I have set my wp-config.php file to include

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );
```

I have then restarted apache with the following to make sure changes are made.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Yet when I login to the dashboard I am still greeted with

```
Current memory limit: 40 MB | We recommend setting memory to at least 128MB
```

I have checked my .htaccess file also (which has only mod_rewrite settings) and I still get the current memory limit : 40mb in the dashboard.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to like this way: Edit this **wp-config.php** file

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must write it at the top of the file **wp-config.php**

```
<?php
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

1. Set define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); in wp-config.php
2. Plugin was defining the memory limit, therefore was being called twice.
3. Deleted pesky plugin, now ok.

Comment: Which plugin? Can you add to answer so we can avoid it?